# how to display single data with database-relationship or eloquent in laravel in my component vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, article

i am getting a problem of viewing my SINGLE ARTICLE with database-relationship using Vue js and laravel api. please help me.

this is my code of getting single article

````
    export default {
        data(){
        return{
            article: [],

        }
    },
        mounted() {
            axios.get(`/api/article/${this.$route.params.id}`).then(({ data }) => (this.article = data))
        }
    }
</script>```

BUT it's NOT WORKING WHEN I DISPLAY ON TOP LIKE ```{{article.id}}``` but if i try to ```{{article}}``` it will display my single article AND ALSO HOW CAN A DISPLAY IN MY ARTICLE THE AUTHOR BASE ON USER_ID PLEEEEAAASSSEEE HELP MEE. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it inside v-for to iterate the data inside of arcticle.

```
<ul>
 <li v-for="val in article">{{val.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Much better if you use plural on your data so that it will be easily read.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked :) please help me how can i get the name of the author using user_id in my article table

Comment: Is that included in this axios get? axios.get(`/api/article/${this.$route.params.id}`). If not you can manage the data that will be returned by article. You should have relationship between user and the article.

Comment: my code in my controller is `$article = DB::table('articles')
                    ->join('users','articles.user_id','=','users.id')
                    ->select('users.name as author','articles.title as title','articles.created_at as created_at','articles.content as content')
                    ->where('articles.id','=',$id)
                    ->get();` but it didn't display to my front end when i call it {{val.author}}

Comment: `article: [{id: 17, author: "author name", title: "Consequatur rerum doloremque labore libero.",…}]
0: {id: 17, author: "author name", title: "Consequatur rerum doloremque labore libero.",…}
author: "author name"
content: "Alias laudantium necessitatibus ea beatae recusandae at. Quia deleniti est facere quia. Iure qui in eum sint. Voluptate sed ducimus cum deserunt ipsa."
created_at: "2019-11-07 02:10:12"
id: 17
title: "Consequatur rerum doloremque labore libero."`  its displayed in my XRH  but when i called in in my template as {{val.author}} it didnt work

Comment: Maybe the returned data is messed up.

Comment: i figured it out thanks a lot :)  code is `v-for="article in articles.data"` which is supposed to be `article in articles.article` thanks for helping